# Import multiple resource files in app.xaml wpf

Tags: wpf

[Running on Windows 8]
I know how to import a single one, like this:

```
<Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles\MyCombobox.xaml"/>       
 </Application.Resources>
```

but I want something like this:

```
<Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles\X.xaml"/>       
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles\Y.xaml"/>       
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles\Z.xaml"/>       
 </Application.Resources>
```

I get:

> The property Resource can only be set once!

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should merge that dictionaries.

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles\X.xaml"/>       
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles\Y.xaml"/>       
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles\Z.xaml"/>       
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

More in [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br208801)

**UPDATE**

Of course, you should wrap property usage in `ResourceDictionary` tag.

Comment: I get nested properties are not supported, added a picture.